# How to write an onClick event

Tags: php, onclick

```
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr><td>". $row["moduleCode"]. "</td><td>". $row["moduleTitle"]. "</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
```

This is part of my php code. How could I write an 'onClick' event so the 'moduleCode' is put into an input tag?

Comment: I guess, you need to solve this problem via JS, but not php.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a solution with or without a library? Do you want to register the event later or do you like to use onclick=""?

A simple solution for onclick="" on a button, or whatever should be your click target, could look like this:

```
<?php
$rows = [
    [
        'moduleTitle' => 'test',
        'moduleCode' => 'testcode'
    ]
];

echo "<table>";

foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
    echo '<tr>'
        . '  <td id="code_' . $key . '">' . $row['moduleCode'] . '</td>'
        . '  <td>' . $row['moduleTitle']. '</td>'
        . '  <td><button tpye="button" onclick="copyToInput(' . $key . ')">copy code</button></td>'
        . '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
echo '<input type="text" name="target" id="target" value="">';
?>

<script>
    function copyToInput(key) {
        codeElem = document.querySelector('#code_' + key);

        if (codeElem) {
            targetElem = document.querySelector('#target');
            targetElem.value = codeElem.innerHTML;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I was looking to be able to click the particular cell (so either module code or module title) and then the value which is in that cell is then put into a <input type='txt'> tag

Comment: So you just need to put the "onclick" attribute at the <td>-element that should trigger the event and the code I wrote will be working exactly as you need it.

As it's working with the ID of the moduleCode elements, you can put the onclick event on any element inside your loop and it will copy the code to the target input element.